# Is there a better word or phrase to describe ‘exercise’, as in, working out?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

The best I can think of is physical training, or physical discipline.

Comment: *Routine exercise*, maybe.

Comment: It depends on the context: the sentence, paragraph, etc.

Comment: I’m just curious if there are other ways to describe the idea, if one views / hears this word in a (negative, or difficult) light.

Comment: Do physical training or physical discipline not meet your needs? If not, why not? Please provide a sample sentence, with a blank where you want this phrase to be, so that we can better understand the situation.

Comment: There is not a sample sentence, as I am mostly focusing on the idea of exercise, and wondering about other ways of describing it. I can't really find many other terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I prefer *fitness regimen*.